# Remove data-attr of cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a very simple (it looks like) thing: clone already existring html-element, modify it's attribute and append in on the page. And it doesn't work, and I have no idea why.

Here is a simple demo:

Hello World

Change color

```
// js
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  var row = $('#banner-message').find('.test:first').clone(true);
  row.removeData('event-num');
  //row.data('event-num', 500);
  $('#banner-message').find('.test:last').after(row);
})
```

Here is a jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jn1wm9da/

It neither deletes nor overrides (actually I want to delete it) already existing attribute. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.data()` method stores information in a jQuery object that is connected to the element, and doesn't effect `data-*` attributes. Data attributes are just attributes, and you should use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), and [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to add/change or remove them.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  var row = $('#banner-message').find('.test:first').clone(true);
  row.removeAttr('data-event-num');
  row.attr('data-event-num', 500);
  $('#banner-message').find('.test:last').after(row);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="test" data-event-num='0'>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was sure that this method works with data attrs fine.

Comment: `.data()` can get the data from `data-*` attributes, but can't change or remove them,

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery Documentation for [removeData](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/)

> Note that .removeData() will only remove data from jQuery's internal .data() cache, and any corresponding data- attributes on the element will not be removed.

Try using

```
row.removeAttr('data-event-num');
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

Use `row.attr('data-event-num', null);` to remove the data attribute

```
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  var row = $('#banner-message').find('.test:first').clone(true);
  //row.removeData('event-num');
  row.attr('data-event-num', null);
  $('#banner-message').find('.test:last').after(row);
})
```